# Perl Ora2Pg on Ubuntu

Tags: perl, oracle, postgresql, ubuntu

I just tried Ora2Pg on my Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope.

First of all, the installation was hard, but after downloading a few debs & rpms here & there, I was finally managed to install ora2pg via synaptic.

However, when I try to run this command

`ora2pg /tmp/ora2pg.conf`

I am getting a

> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/DynaLoader.pm line 196.
>
> at (eval 14) line 3
>
> Compilation failed in require at (eval 14) line 3.
>
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
>
> at /usr/share/perl5/Ora2Pg.pm line 566

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Note: I don't perl. I just started browsing a bit it because of this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct sequence for installation:

```
apt-get install libdbi-perl
apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
apt-get install libaio1
apt-get install make
apt-get install alien
apt-get install rpm
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

download DBD-Oracle-1.74 or last version 
download DBD-Pg-3.5.3 or last version 
download DBI-1.636  or last version 
download ora2pg-17.5 or last version 
download oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
download oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
download oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

after extract rpm package and install:

```
alien oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
alien oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
alien oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
dpkg -i oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.deb
dpkg -i oracle-instantclient12.1-devel_12.1.0.2.0-2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.deb
```

then:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

the path of oracle client installation

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/
```

then, istall the perl extension for Oracle and Postgres

```
cd  DBI-1.636
perl Makefile.PL
make && makeinstall

cd DBD-Oracle-1.74 o DBD-Oracle-1.64
perl Makefile.PL
make && makeinstall

cd DBD-Pg-3.5.3
perl Makefile.PL
make && makeinstall
```

and finally, install

```
cd ora2pg-17.x
perl Makefile.PL
make && makeinstall
```

check in the version is correct

```
ora2pg -v
```

and last configure `ora2pg.conf` on `/etc/ora2pg/`

insert in file, the configuration for connect to Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: is there a reason why you are installing alien twice in the first sequence?

Comment: also i see that you have the dpkg install twice

Answer (score 1):

`DBD::Oracle` can't find the Oracle client libraries because they're not in your library path. If you don't have the Oracle client libraries and you don't have a sysadmin to provide them for you, then you need to get the "Oracle Instantclient" package from the oracle website and install it. If you already have Instantclient installed, then you need to add its `lib` directory (something like `/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient/lib` or `/opt/ora/instantclient10_1/lib`) to your library path -- either by adding a line to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `ldconfig` as root, or by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-installation steps:

1. ORACLE Client must be installed and `ORACLE_HOME` must be set.
2. Install perl (version 5.6 and above)

Installation steps:

3. Install DBI (database interface module)

   `apt-get install cpanminus` (for ubuntu)
   `yum install cpanminus` (for Linux)

   ```
   cpanm DBI
   ```
4. Install `DBD::Oracle` and `DBD::Pg`

   ```
   cpanm DBD::Oracle
   cpanm DBD::Pg
   ```
5. Download the latest version of ora2pg from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ora2pg/ and run the following commands:

   ```
   tar -xvf ora2pg-18.0.tar
   cd ora2pg-18.0/
   perl Makefile.PL
   su root
   make
   make install
   ```
6. Do the changes as per req
   By default Ora2Pg will look to `ora2pg.conf` configuration file into `/etc/ora2pg/` directory.

   ```
   ORACLE_HOME /app/oracle/product/11.2.0
   ORACLE_DSN dbi:Oracle:host=[hostname];sid=[SID name]
   ORACLE_USER [SYSTEM]
   ORACLE_PWD [password]
   USER_GRANTS 1
   ```
7. Check the version of pra2pg:

   ```
   ora2pg SHOW_VERSION
   ```
8. Run the below command

   ```
   ora2pg -c /etc/ora2pg/ora2pg.conf
   ora2pg -c /etc/ora2pg/ora2pg.conf -p -P 10 -J 10 -L 1000000
   ```
9. .sql file will create in the current directory have converted data into PostgreSql

Hope this will work.